# Polymer this.$ undefined in filter

Tags: polymer

I have a function called formatDate. This functions uses `this.$` to access a global function in a global element. The only problem is that I am getting an error that says `this.$` is undefined. I am not sure why that would ever be undefined. It is defined in the ready callback.

EDIT: Added code example. My problem is seen below in the formatDate function. `this.$` is undefined.

```
<link rel="import" href="app-globals.html">

<polymer-element name="message-element" attributes="message">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      .message {
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-left: 6px;
        color: white;
        clear: both;
        max-width: 700px;
      }

      .sent-message {
        background-color: #3F51B5;
        float: right;
      }

      .received-message {
        background-color: #C5CAE9;
        float: left;
      }

      .sent-time {
        font-size: 70%;
        opacity: .54;
      }
      .clear {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="message {{message.type}}-message">
      <app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>
      <div>
          {{message.message}}
      </div>
      <div class="sent-time">
          {{message.sentDateTime | formatDate}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      formatDate: function(dateStr)
      {
        //console.log(this.$);
        if(this.$ != null)
        {
          return this.$.globals.formatDate(dateStr);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: some code would help. but if you have a callback inside another function you must pass in "this". that can be done by assigning a variable like "scope = this" then use scope in the following function or you can use the bind() method "setTimeout(function () {}.bind(this), 100);"

Comment: I have updated the question to include a code example.